# What is the most elegant way to remove an array of properties from an object immutably in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, immutability

Not sure if I'm trying to accomplish too much here in an elegant way, but let's say I have an object as follows:

```
const obj = { foo: 'bar', prop: 'str', hi: 'hello' };
```

And then I have an array of properties I want to remove from that object:

```
const keys = ['prop', 'hi'];
```

I'm looking for the best way I can **immutably** get an output of:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

I was looking into using destructuring assignments but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with an array of properties unless it has a static length:

```
({ [keys[0]]: value, [keys[1]]: value, ...output }) = o;
```

Maybe there's an alternative way to do the above line but using mapping?

Thanks!

Comment: By "immutably", do you mean that you want to create a new object with the same keys, but ommiting the ones named in `keys`?

Comment: Define *"elegant"*.

Comment: @tao: [I know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)

Comment: He didn't ask for *"an elegant solution"* (which *"I know it when I see it"* sort of applies to). He asked for *"the most elegant"* one. Being quantifiable, it needs definition.

Comment: Which is the most elegant?  I think I'll know it when I see it.  :-).  More seriously, though, in [Simple Made Easy](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/), Rich Hickey describes a reasonably objective definition of simplicity in code.  To my mind, simplicity and elegance go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the array and use delete to delete each matching keys.

To make a copy of the object you have you could use the spread operator

```js
const keys = ['prop', 'hi'];
const obj = { foo: 'bar', prop: 'str', hi: 'hello' };
const newobj={...obj}
keys.forEach(o=> delete newobj[o])
console.log(obj)
console.log(newobj)
```

Here is another approach using `Object.fromEntries` and `filter`, `some`

```js
const keys = ['prop', 'hi'];
const obj = { foo: 'bar', prop: 'str', hi: 'hello' };
res=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(o=>!keys.some(k=>o[0]==k)))
console.log(res)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This mutates `obj` which seems to be disallowed from the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for pointing that out, fixed now

Comment: your first one is nice because it doesn't run the slow [].includes() a lot and is highly readable.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you, although the second approach is recommended if the object is too complex to be cloned with the spread operator

Comment: Why the above over `....filter (([k]) => keys .includes (k))`, Dan Davis' objection notwithstanding?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I didn't mean it's not withstanding, I just think for deeply nested objects it will be cumbersome to make a deep copy and so with the first approach that won't be possible with the spread operator. performance wise I think the first approach is definitely better, but I am interested to know what you think :)

Comment: I'd have to benchmark to know which was better, and I wouldn't even bother unless it was a demonstrable hotspot in my code

Comment: Nice and straightforward, and a one-liner is just what I was looking for when I said "elegant!" Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of the `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`, and the Array `.filter` methods. Then this operation becomes quite straightforward:

```js
function removeKeysFromObj(obj, keys) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => !keys.includes(key)));
}

const obj = { foo: 'bar', prop: 'str', hi: 'hello' };
const keys = ['prop', 'hi'];

const newObj = removeKeysFromObj(obj, keys);

console.log("New object:", newObj);

// And note the original is unmodified:
console.log("Original object:", obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to think in the reverse way: map over the keys in the original object and **keep** the ones not in the list:

```
function removeKeys(obj, keys) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(k => !keys.includes(k))
        .reduce((newObj, k) => {
            newObj[k] = obj[k];
            return newObj
        }, {});
```

Comment: By `obj.keys()` do you mean `Object.keys(obj)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this.

```js
const obj = { foo: 'bar', prop: 'str', hi: 'hello' };
const keys = ['prop', 'hi'];
let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((current, item) => (keys.includes(item) || (current[item] = obj[item]), current), {});
console.log(result);
```